# Apache camel how to apply readLock on FTP component from route

Tags: java, apache-camel

Am having an FTP route from where i will be downloading files i want to apply readLock on it, so when something is being written on that file, i will not download it in the middle, i read about it in file component, but iam not clear on how to apply this option on my FTP route, Please help
below is the sample code of my route

from("ftp://localhost:21/export?username=user&password=123&idempotent=true")
           .to("file:tmp/inbound")

Answer (score 1):

Add &readLock=changed option in from uri. It will avoid to download the file which being written. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the below link here they mentioned what options are there and what each option strategy does

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/EIP_Component_Reference/files/_IDU_File2.html

Hope this is helpful.